# Where to place DeleteNode in Java Node class?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following Node class used to implement linked list:

```
class Node {

  Node next = null;
  int data;

  public Node (int d) {
    data = d;
  }

  void AppendToTail (int d) {
    Node end = new Node(d);
    Node current = this;
    while (current.next != null) {
      current = current.next;
    }

    current.next = end;
  }

}
```

And I want to create a method that given a Node, it will delete it from a Linked list.  So, I know how to create a function like this. But I am unsure how would I make it fit in my class.

```
Node deleteNode(Node head, Node toDelete) {
    Node n = head;
    if (n.data == toDelete.data) {
      return head.next;
    }

    while (n.next != null) {
      if (n.next.data == toDelete.data) {
         n.next = n.next.next;
         return head;
      }
      n = n.next;
    }
    return head;
  }
```

However, I am failing to see how would I put that into my Node class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement that method or how to actually write it syntactically in the class?

Comment: How to write it syntactically in the class. I am not sure if I am supposed to pass the head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function a static function in the Node class.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I see would be you not putting the append and delete functions into the linked list class rather than in the node class. You should have the node class be totally separate from the linked list class. Therefore you can have the append and delete methods in the linked list class that add and delete instances of your node class. This helps you because then you don't have to worry about the node class one its created, you can just focus on the implementation in the linked list class.